# Generic Methods with user defined types

Tags: c#, generics, user-defined-types

Scenario I am facing is I have a base class

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string SomeVal { get; set; }
    public BaseClass(string someVal)
    {
        this.SomeVal = someVal;
    }
}
```

and two other classes that inherit from BaseClass using the constructor from BaseClass

```
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public ClassA(string someVal) : base (someVal)
        {
        }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public ClassB(string someVal) : base (someVal)
        {
        }
}
```

I'd like to create a generic method that can take either `ClassA` types or `ClassB` types to modify the `SomeVal` value.
I have tried doing this

```
public static void func<T>(T className)
{
    className.SomeVal = "Hello World";
}
```

but obviously the compiler doesn't know what SomeVal is, I have also tried `public class ClassA<T> : BaseClass` but still at the same point of it not knowing what `SomeVal` is, additionally, all uses of `ClassA` in the code no longer work with the error `Using the generic type 'ClassA<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

I have also considered overloads for the functionality I require, but that can get tedious for my scenario as I have multiple classes that inherit from `BaseClass`, and the method I would be creating isn't a big one either

Comment: Why do you have a generic method in the first place?  You want the parameter to always be a `BaseClass`, so why is that not it's type?

Comment: @Servy I thought I needed to pass either `ClassA` or etc. to the method, but now I see passing `BaseClass` works. I'm still training and admittedly not done much programming in about a year due to covid. But it is also nice to know how to use generics for future if I need them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can constrain `T` to `BaseClass`

```
public static void func<T>(T className)
   where T : BaseClass
```

If you aren't doing much with `T`, I would consider making `func` not generic and just take a `BaseClass`

```
public static void func(BaseClass className)
```